# Read dataTable from form2 and send it to form 1 at the start of running

Tags: c#, database, indexoutofrangeexception

I would like to get the data from table 2 in form 2 to form 1 to initialize some variables, so I made a method to return the specific value:

```
public String pass(int i, int j)
    {

            return editInfoDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value.ToString();

    }
```

but there is an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

As I know that the data is always stored in the table so why it returns that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties for accessing the data one form into another.

For Example, If you have the table getting populated with some data on say Form A, add something like this in Form A...

```
public string ValueNeedToUse { get; set; }
```

Assign the required value in table to this property,

```
FirstName = this.sampleDBDataSet.BasicInfo[ColCount]["FirstName"].ToString();
```

Initialize your parent form i.e. Form A in second form say, Form B...

```
public frmsecond(frmMain ImportedForm)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        strFirstName = ImportedForm.FirstName;
}
```

and That's it!!